# Structure a site with multiple locations with categories, structure or "multisite"?

Tags: categories, structure, multi-site

I'm proposing to use Craft for a company that runs multiple golf courses. Along with some general pages for the company as a whole, each location (course) is to have it's own microsite, for want of a better phrase. At the moment each location will have the same pages (but that could change in the future), along with a news section.

I think I can achieve this with a combination of categories and structures, but I'd be keen to know if anyone has any other ideas. (Possibly "multisite" with locals?)

My thoughts are:

- Homepage - Single
- Global About - Single
- Global Golf Pros - Channel
- Locations - Structure with individual entry types for each sub page
- Global Contact Us - Single
- News (there's no requirement for this to be global at the moment, but creating multiple news channels seems a little painful) - Channel (with category filed to scope to each location)

Within the Location's channel I can then use relationships for each location's Golf Pros (from the Global Golf Pros channel) and list news articles via twig `craft.entries.section('news').categories('location-x')` and a slightly elongated Entry URL Format "locations/{location.first.slug}/news/{slug}"

Sometimes a picture is worth a 1,000 words, so here goes.

[image: Sitemap]

I feel a little like I'm mixing the use of categories and structures though.

Any thought would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another idea (since that's what you asked for) might be to leverage Relationships more than Entry Types.

I find that those administering the content have a better time with relationships than Entry Types.

Given that your

e.g. if Golf Pros' was a Structure (instead), which contained a **required** field called 'Related Location' your content admin person could logically click **Entries** > **New Entry** > **Golf Pro**

One area this could really help would be News. If a News article (Entry) contained the same 'Related Location' field, I think you'd have a better time templating and also provide a more logical publishing experience for your client.

The same could apply to the other Entry Types you have beneath your Locations; About, How to find us, etc.

As I said - it's only another approach - happy to discuss, Tom.

Matt

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for your thoughts. I like the idea of moving the relationship from the Location's Pro's page to the Pro's entry itself, much simpler as you suggest. What is the advantage of switching the Pro's Channel to a Structure though? Applying the same to the other Entry Types are you suggesting there would be an "About" Channel / Structure with multiple entries that are related to a Location? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Tom. No problem. I only suggested a Structure because the Section wouldn't need a dat/time stamp that a Channel would have. You could use either Channel or Structure. ... To your second question, yes an About Entry would be related to a Location. As I said, just an idea - I always try to consider the logic a content administrator will face when working in the CMS. Best.

Comment: Hi Matt. Sorry for the (really) delayed reply. I took this approach in the end and it worked out great. Thanks for your input. Marked your answer as correct.